# Wordpress/MySQL (InnoDB) tables get fragmented near instantaneously after optimizing tables?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, innodb

So I originally ran `mysqltuner` and it kept saying (on a fresh Wordpress install, using Percona InnoDB with random dummy data for Wordpress posts) that there was fragmented tables. I don't know if this is the proper way to check for fragmented tables or not:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, CONCAT(ROUND(data_length / ( 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'MB')        DATA, CONCAT(ROUND(data_free / ( 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'MB')FREE from information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql') and Data_free > 0;
```

but that spits out:

```
+----------------+-------------+--------+--------+
| TABLE_SCHEMA   | TABLE_NAME  | DATA   | FREE   |
+----------------+-------------+--------+--------+
| db_wordpress   | wp_postmeta | 2.52MB | 4.00MB |
| db_wordpress   | wp_posts    | 1.52MB | 4.00MB |
+----------------+-------------+--------+--------+
```

So I'm unsure if those tables are truly fragmented or not. I've ran:

```
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta ENGINE='InnoDB';
```

which supposedly is the correct way to "optimize" InnoDB tables? That then made the above query show:

```
+----------------+-------------+--------+--------+
| TABLE_SCHEMA   | TABLE_NAME  | DATA   | FREE   |
+----------------+-------------+--------+--------+
| db_wordpress   | wp_postmeta | 0.02MB | 4.00MB |
| db_wordpress   | wp_posts    | 1.52MB | 4.00MB |
+----------------+-------------+--------+--------+
```

Now, `mysqltuner` was still saying those two tables were fragmented, so I tried:

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE wp_posts;
```

When running the above query then put the "data" column back to the original of 2.52MB...

So I'm unsure what's going on exactly? Let alone why exactly the tables (particularly `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta`) would be fragmented as my understanding was (primarily?) deletes were the big cause of fragmentation? If it's also inserts would I have fragmentation issues on pretty much every new post that's made in Wordpress considering that's what seems to have caused the tables to get fragmented in the first place?

Either way, I'm just unsure if that query above is the correct one to check for fragmentation and if so, would `ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta ENGINE='InnoDB'` or `OPTIMIZE TABLE wp_posts` be the correct query to run to optimize the table and if so why would the query still show as fragmented?

EDIT:

Percona's Config Wizard gave me:

```
# MyISAM #
key-buffer-size                = 32M
myisam-recover                 = FORCE,BACKUP

# SAFETY #
max-allowed-packet             = 16M
max-connect-errors             = 1000000
skip-name-resolve
#sql-mode                       = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY # I disabled this due to problems with WP/Plugins
sysdate-is-now                 = 1
innodb                         = FORCE
#innodb-strict-mode             = 0 # I disabled this due to problems with WP/Plugins

# DATA STORAGE #
datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql/

# BINARY LOGGING #
log-bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
expire-logs-days               = 14
sync-binlog                    = 1

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size                 = 96M # I tweaked this due to mysqltuner recommendation
max-heap-table-size            = 96M # I tweaked this due to mysqltuner recommendation
query-cache-type               = 1 # I tweaked this due to mysqltuner recommendation
query-cache-size               = 96M # I tweaked this due to mysqltuner recommendation
max-connections                = 100
thread-cache-size              = 16
open-files-limit               = 65535
table-definition-cache         = 1024
table-open-cache               = 256

# INNODB #
innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0 # I added this when testing
innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 64M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 2
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 400
```

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you are storing all your tables in the central tablespace `ibdata1`, because when you do that, the `data_free` for *all* tables is reported as the amount of unused space in the whole `ibdata1` file.

In other words, comparing `data_length` to `data_free` is not a very useful way to measure fragmentation unless you use `innodb_file_per_table=1`.

`ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta ENGIN=InnoDB` will indeed do a table restructure and rebuild secondary indexes. It makes sense that the pages will be filled better, and so your 2.52MB was rewritten down to 0.02MB (which is probably one or two 16KB data pages).

At the scale you're working with, I wouldn't worry about fragmentation at all. Even storing the data in the fragmented form only took 2 and half MB, so your buffer pool is still only a fraction filled. The reason to attend to fragmentation is when you are trying to stretch your buffer pool to fit more of your data. In your case, it's going to fit no matter what.

---

Re your comment and additional info:

```
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 400
```

This is not a good value to set. The unit for this variable is in *bytes*, so you have requested an awfully tiny buffer pool. In fact, InnoDB will disregard your config and instead use the minimum value of 5MB. If you check your MySQL error log, you may see this:

```
[Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 5.0M
```

This is way too small for any typical production web site. The size of the buffer pool is a crucial tuning parameter if you want to get good performance. The buffer pool should be large enough to hold your *working set*, that is the pages of data that are most frequently used by your application.  See [MySQL Performance Blog's post "10 MySQL settings to tune after installation"](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2014/01/28/10-mysql-settings-to-tune-after-installation/).

That said, your database might be so small that 5.0MB is adequate -- for now.  But keep in mind that the default size of the buffer pool in MySQL 5.6 is 128MB.

You have allocated 32MB to your key buffer, which is used only for MyISAM indexes. [I recommend *against* using MyISAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb/17706717#17706717) for any tables in most cases. If you have no MyISAM tables, then memory would be better allocated to your InnoDB buffer pool.

You also allocated 96MB to your query cache. The query cache has some downsides to it -- depending on your site's traffic, it could actually hurt more than help. Unless you're getting a lot of bang for the buck from it, I would disable it (`query_cache_type=0` *and* `query_cache_size=0`), and use that RAM for the buffer pool. See [MySQL Performance Blog's post "MySQL Query Cache"](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/27/mysql-query-cache/) for more information on this.

---

Re your second comment:

No, the innodb_buffer_pool_size is not in MB, it's in bytes. You can make it MB only if you add the "M" suffix to the number.

[The MySQL 5.6 manual on `innodb_buffer_pool_size`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) says:

> The size in bytes of the buffer pool, the memory area where InnoDB caches table and index data. The default value is 128MB.

I just tested it with MySQL 5.5.36 -- not Percona Server, just stock MySQL community edition. I confirm that when I set `innodb_buffer_pool_size=400`, what I get is 5.0MB, which is the documented minimum size.

I also tested with MySQL 5.1.70, and I see this in the error log when I start with the buffer pool size set to 400:

```
140203  9:46:20 [Warning] option 'innodb-buffer-pool-size': signed value 400 adjusted to 1048576
140203  9:46:20  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 1.0M
```

MySQL 5.1's minimum buffer pool size is documented to be 1.0MB.

Comment: Thanks for the response Bill, I am indeed using `innodb-file-per-table          = 1`.

Comment: Please see my edit to my original post at the bottom. Basically I'm just looking to make sure (as small as my test environment is currently, which will eventually be production) is as efficient as possible with my setup. I'm currently using a VPS with 1 core, 1g ram.

Comment: Bill, unsure if Percona handles the config differently but that buffer-pool-size is definitely in MB as if I try setting it to something like 900 (again the VPS has 1gb ram) it fails to allocate since there's already 150MB of ram used.

As for the query cache, the Percona tool made those both 0, but mysqltuner complaining I figured "what the heck we'll see what happens" since it's still a test environment. :P

I'll check some more value, thanks again for the update!

Comment: In addition to Bill's great answer, I should note that `Data_free` reported for InnoDB is actually fairly useless as it only reports free space in the tablespace's "free extent list" (`fsp_get_available_space_in_free_extents`). This is not really any indication of a problem or fragmentation. I would say `mysqltuner` is just incorrect.

Comment: @jeremycole, thanks, yeah, I forgot about that. IIRC, the data_free is *only* the space taken by 100% unused extents (an extent is 1MB worth of pages). So you could have a lot of actual fragmentation within its partially-filled pages, which is not reported by data_free at all.

Comment: @BillKarwin Yes, exactly, it completely ignores partially-used extents ("not_full extent list") and partially-filled pages. You could, in the worst case, have one page per extent actually used, and each of those pages half full, storing only ~800 KB of data in ~100 MB of tablespace, and `Data_free` would report "0"! Oy!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, very interesting Bill as my setting is definitely in MB as mysqltuner shows max memory used is ~510MB, 100 connections at 1.1mb + the 400mb buffer pool size. Also, if I adjust it something like 900 MySQL fails to start with error_log stating it can't allocate 900mb to the innodb buffer.

Definitely must be a different between Percona and MySQL then.

Comment: I just tested Percona Server 5.6.15 and the behavior is the same as stock MySQL. innodb_buffer_pool is in bytes, not megabytes, unless you append "M" to it.